# QFT in termed of electric force field vs magnetic force field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics

I have very distracting problem found no satisfactory answer.. I found many satisfactory answer from your website with my conceptual problems.

1. In Quantum Field Theory, Electric Force Field and Magnetic Force Field are two different Fields in sense of virtual and real photon.If not how they relate?
2. We say Electromagnetic Wave? If it associated with EM Force field why it doesn't deflect or has no charge? termed EM wave has no Electric and Magnetic properties?
3. If Matter Field interact with Force Field or more specific EM Force Field virtual photons poses electric and magnetic force $1/r^2$ law on other matter through virtual photon. why these properties not in real photons?
4. If virtual photon has $3$ polarization, $1$ extra polarization longitudinal polarization from real photon explanation what i found from google. Does this polarization state of EM Force Field responsible for  charge of particle? if it is can we produce real photon with this polarization state. or resolve from unpolarized light.

Comment: This is many questions in one.  Could you choose just one and write in more detail?  Right now, it's hard to see where your confusion is.

Comment: First i want to know . How charge is associated with Force particle and elementary particle?

Comment: How charge and spin are associated with Force particle FIELDS and elementary particle FIELDS?

Answer (score 2):

1. No they are not, they are different aspects of the same thing, the electromagnetic field. And this does not have anything to do with real and virtual photons whatsoever.
2. Yes, the EM field doesn't have charge. That doesn't mean that it "doesn't have electric properties", it interacts with charged matter.
3. Virtual photons don't really exist, they're just things that appear in Feynman diagrams, which we use to calculate e.g. forces between matter.
4. No. The longitudinal polarization doesn't have anything to do with charges, it only appears to make calculations easier (remember again that those virtual photons are not real anyway).

Note: To be honest, I don't think you'll get very far just asking questions in the internet. You need to learn some of the very basics and seem to have quite some misconceptions. There are free physics lectures available online.

Comment: What is Static Electric and Static Magnetic Field . It associate with matter or EM Field?